Uniswap router V3 exactOutputSingle failing without proper error
I need to make a swap with Javascript web3.js and uniswap V3 router (for testing I use BSC)
Here my code
import Web3 from 'web3';
import config from './components/config.js';
import BigNumber from 'bignumber.js';

const { rpc_ETH, key } = config;
const web3 = new Web3(rpc_ETH);
const owner = '0xFE9b59FdC1Ff3eD1452e4bCAC2758EC607bc6373';
const baseToken = '0x62694d43ccb9b64e76e38385d15e325c7712a735';
const fee = '3000';

const routerV3ABI = [
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        components: [
          { internalType: "address", name: "tokenIn", type: "address" },
          { internalType: "address", name: "tokenOut", type: "address" },
          { internalType: "uint24", name: "fee", type: "uint24" },
          { internalType: "address", name: "recipient", type: "address" },
          { internalType: "uint256", name: "deadline", type: "uint256" },
          { internalType: "uint256", name: "amountOut", type: "uint256" },
          { internalType: "uint256", name: "amountInMaximum", type: "uint256" },
          {
            internalType: "uint160",
            name: "sqrtPriceLimitX96",
            type: "uint160",
          },
        ],
        internalType: "struct ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams",
        name: "params",
        type: "tuple",
      },
    ],
    name: "exactOutputSingle",
    outputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "amountIn", type: "uint256" }],
    stateMutability: "payable",
    type: "function",
  },
]

const routerV3Address = '0xB971eF87ede563556b2ED4b1C0b0019111Dd85d2';
const routerV3 = new web3.eth.Contract(routerV3ABI, routerV3Address);
const WETH = '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c'; 
// for testing I do the swap on BSC, so we use WBNB and all other addresses for BSC (RouterV3, baseToken, owner etc.)


async function BuyV3() {
  try {

    // * routerV3Address is approved max amount to WBNB contract

    const deadline = (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 1).toString();
    const amountInMaximum = new BigNumber('1374199245852859').plus(new BigNumber('1374199245852859').times(0.1)).integerValue(BigNumber.ROUND_CEIL).toString();
  
    const data = [
      WETH, //tokenIn
      baseToken, //tokenOut
      fee, // fee
      owner, // recipient
      deadline, // deadline
      '100000000000000000000', // amountOut
      amountInMaximum, // amountInMaximum
      '0' // sqrtPriceLimitX96
    ]

    // * example data:
    // [
    //   '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c',
    //   '0x62694d43ccb9b64e76e38385d15e325c7712a735',
    //   '3000',
    //   '0xFE9b59FdC1Ff3eD1452e4bCAC2758EC607bc6373',
    //   '1717815046',
    //   '100250000000000000000',
    //   '1511619170438145',
    //   '0'
    // ]

    const functionSignature = routerV3.methods.exactOutputSingle(data).encodeABI();
  
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(owner, 'latest');
    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();

    // the gas estimation will fail, no clear error
    const gasEstimate = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
      from: owner,
      to: routerV3Address,
      data: functionSignature,
    });

    const gasLimit = Math.round(gasEstimate * 1.5);

    const tx = {
      nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
      from: owner,
      to: routerV3Address,
      data: functionSignature,
      gasPrice: gasPrice.toString(),
      gasLimit: gasLimit.toString(),
    };

    const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, key);
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);

    return receipt;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

  const receipt = await BuyV3();

  console.log(receipt)

for some reason it keeps failing and the error is not telling me what/why is't failing.
here the error
ContractExecutionError: Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract
    at Web3RequestManager._isReverted (file:///C:/Users/sven_/OneDrive/Documenten/Sv3n/Work/Deddy/Bot/node_modules/web3-core/lib/esm/web3_request_manager.js:305:19)
    at Web3RequestManager._processJsonRpcResponse (file:///C:/Users/sven_/OneDrive/Documenten/Sv3n/Work/Deddy/Bot/node_modules/web3-core/lib/esm/web3_request_manager.js:251:42)
    at Web3RequestManager.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/sven_/OneDrive/Documenten/Sv3n/Work/Deddy/Bot/node_modules/web3-core/lib/esm/web3_request_manager.js:150:29)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (file:///C:/Users/sven_/OneDrive/Documenten/Sv3n/Work/Deddy/Bot/node_modules/web3-core/lib/esm/web3_request_manager.js:20:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  innerError: [Eip838ExecutionError: execution reverted] {
    innerError: undefined,
    code: -32000,
    receipt: undefined,
    data: undefined
  },
  code: 310,
  receipt: undefined
}

I searched for several days now, but other then uniswap SDK I can not find a proper example of how this should work and what exactly is needed. I did approve max amount to WBNB contract with routerV3 as spender.
I also tried to set different types of input (number, string, BigInt, hex) but non is working.
I got BNB and WBNB enough in the wallet to make the swap.
Any help is welcome.
